# Enterprise library v5 exception

Tags: vb.net, enterprise-library

I am getting the following exception while executing queries through enterprise library v5.

```
SqlCommand.DeriveParameters failed because the SqlCommand.CommandText property value is an invalid multipart name "SELECT QUERY", the current limit of "4" is insufficient.
```

Code:

```
Try
   Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("DatabaseName")
   reader = db.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text, query)
Catch ex As Exception
   Throw ex
End Try
```

This code block was running fine till yesterday. Suddenly this error is showing up in the logs.

Comment: What is the value of query?

Comment: I don't think this is an Enterprise Library problem. Most likely the inputs to this code have changed (the value of query).